# visual basic val() function in php

Tags: php, vb6

This may be an easy question for some but I'm having a hard time finding the answer to it. I've looked everywhere online but all the threads I've checked out don't have an actual answer that works.

Question: What is the php equivalent for the vb val() function?

It would also be great if you could point me to a page that may have a list of vb to php functions.

I hope this question doesn't piss any one off!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know VB, what does `val()` do?

Comment: You'd probably simply cast the string to an integer or float as appropriate; alternatively use intval() or floatval()

Comment: Val Function in Visual Basic.net 2008 is used to return the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type. @Barmar

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you just explain how I would go about your solution?

Comment: I doubt there would be a direct replacement for many functions from vb in php.

Comment: If there's a web site with a list, I'm sure you can find it with google as easily as we can.

Answer (score 2):

Use `intval()` to convert the string to an integer, `floatval()` to convert it to floating point.

```
$str = "123.456 abc";
$int = intval($str); // $int = 123
$float = floatval($str); // $float = 123.456
```

It's not a perfect replacement, though. `Val()` ignores spaces, so `Val("12 34") = 1234`, but `intval("12 34") = 12`. You could remove spaces with `str_replace()` before calling `intval()` or `floatval()`.

Comment: thanks! it works when I remove the spaces using 'str_replace' and then converting the string using 'intval($str)'

Answer (score 1):

VB's val() does this: "Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type"

The closest built in PHP functions that act like VB's val() is:

```
intval( $var );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

and

```
floatval( $var );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Answer (score 0):

You could just cast your var to the given type.

```
$x = '10.4a';
$a = (int) $x; // $a = 10;
$b = (float) $x; // $b = 10.4;
```